# Photo editing with touch screen

Tags: photoshop, editing

Can a Wacom Intuos Pro be used with Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: Who exactly are you referring to by "you recommended"? This posts on this site are from a collection of users, and we frequently disagree on many things :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall no we don't. =)

Comment: I think the edited question has lost the original meaning and became rather useless since the answer is obviously YES. The first part of the question is IMO the actual question: in which way is Intuos better than touch screen ? And the answer would be: because you hold a pen and you have access to mor eprecision, plus tilt, plus pressure, plus eventually rotation data, which can be useful for drawing-like tasks.

Comment: @Soleil - unless we're talking about a Cintiq :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Windows or Mac computer is compatible with the Wacom Intuos Pro, it can be used as an input device with Adobe Photoshop. As with any input device, it will work best if the latest drivers for it are installed on your computing device.

It's included in this article at 'Tablet Under Budget':

[The Best Tablets for Photoshop – Our Top Picks for Best Photo-Editing Tablets](https://tabletunderbudget.com/photo-editing-tablets-for-photoshop/)

Some tips for how to set it up for best results are included in this article at 'SLR Lounge.'

[How To Set Up Your Wacom Pen For Better Use In Photoshop, Capture One, & Lightroom](https://www.slrlounge.com/how-to-set-up-your-wacom-pen-for-better-use-in-photoshop-capture-one-lightroom/)

If you are using Photoshop 2018, you may need to use [this workaround](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2398372) to restore certain functionality with Wacom products that worked with Photoshop 2017.

A basic internet search for "Wacom+Photoshop" returns a plethora of resources about using Wacom products, including the Intuos Pro, with Adobe products such as Photoshop.